# A curve can not be both hyperelliptic and trigonal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. We know $C$ is hyperelliptic if and only if it has a linear system of dimension 1 and degree 2, that is it has $g^{1}_{2}$. $C$ is trigonal   if and only if it has a linear system of dimension 1 and degree 3, that is it has $g^{1}_{3}$.

I can prove that if $g(C)\geq 3$, then $C$ can not be both hyperelliptic and trigonal.

However, on the other hand, I get the following. Suppose $C$ is hyperelliptic, then $C$ has $g^{1}_{2}$. So there exists an effective divisor $D$ on $C$ such that $\mathrm{deg}D=2$ and $\mathrm{dim}|D|\geq1$.(not necassarily equal 1 since we could choose the linear subspace). Now choose any point $P$ on $C$, then $\mathrm{deg} (D+P)=3$ and $\mathrm{dim}|D+P|\geq\mathrm{dim}|D|\geq1$. Thus we could get a $g^{1}_{3}$. Thus $C$ is trigonal. However, this is impossible.

Could you tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Yes, I mean $\mathrm{dim} L(D)$, but $\mathrm{dim}|D+P|$ should equal $\mathrm{dim}|D|$ or $\mathrm{dim}|D|+1$

Comment: I believe these definitions should specify that the $g^r_d$ are base point free. If you start with a $g^1_2$ and add a point $P$, I think that one of two things can happen: the dimension of the linear system increases, so you get a $g^2_3$; or the dimension does *not* increase, in which case $P$ is a base point of $g^1_2 + P$. Either way, you don't actually get a trigonal presentation of the curve.